# Write a function in R - calculate value from historical records and add to future records

Tags: r, higher-order-functions

I have the following dataset

```
Name<-c('A','A','B','C','B','C','D','B','C','A','D','C','B','C','A','D','C','B','A','D','C','B')
Rate<-c(12,13,4,8,7,3,6,8,5,4,7,5,9,4,7,2,7,3,9,13,14,12)
Date<-c('1998-11-11', '1992-12-01','2010-06-17', '2001-10-3','2019-4-01', '2020-4-23','2021-2-01', '1995-12-01', 
        '1994-7-11', '2023-3-01','2022-06-17', '1982-10-3','1898-4-01', '2027-4-23','1927-2-01', '2028-12-01',
        '1993-5-21', '2013-2-09','2020-01-17', '1987-4-3','1881-5-01', '2024-5-23')
df<-cbind.data.frame(Name,Rate, Date)
df

   Name  Rate    Date
1     A   12 1998-11-11
2     A   13 1992-12-01
3     B    4 2010-06-17
4     C    8  2001-10-3
5     B    7  2019-4-01
6     C    3  2020-4-23
7     D    6  2021-2-01
8     B    8 1995-12-01
9     C    5  1994-7-11
10    A    4  2023-3-01
11    D    7 2006-06-17
12    C    5  1982-10-3
13    B    9  1898-4-01
14    C    4  2027-4-23
15    A    7  1927-2-01
16    D    2 2028-12-01
17    C    7  1993-5-21
18    B    3  2013-2-09
19    A    9 2020-01-17
20    D   13   1987-4-3
21    C   14  1881-5-01
22    B   12  2024-5-23
```

I want to write a function in R to do the following :
Find the Standard Deviation for each type of Name (A, B, C, D) of historical data. Historical data is any records with Date < Dec'2018. Future records would not be used to calculate the SD for type of Name. I want to then add the SD of the historical data to the future Rates of respective type of Name(A, B, C, D). Future Rates are the one with Date > Dec'2018. Could anyone please help me to write this function?

Below is the function I am working on

```
with(mutate(df,timediff = as.yearmon(Date) - as.yearmon(Sys.Date()) ), 
                         tapply(df$Rate, Name, function(x){
                           ifelse(timediff < 0 ,
                                  x + sd(x),
                                  x)
                         }, simplify=FALSE) )
```

Comment: Please that start by showing some code and that you try...

Comment: My bad, I have added the function I am working on.

Comment: I am not able to get this done. I would appreciate any help to write this function.

Comment: Maybe you want to use data.table here. Something like this: `setDT(df)

df[, time_diff := as.IDate(Date) - as.IDate(Sys.Date())]
df[time_diff < 0, standard_dev := sd(Rate), by = Name]
df[, modified_rate := ifelse(is.na(standard_dev), Rate, Rate + standard_dev)] `

Comment: @mmn : Thank you for your response. Can we implement this in a function? Also, the if-else above adds the SD to the historical records, I want to add the SD to future records.

Comment: Yes, code in the first comment gives the wrong result. This should do it `dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, time_diff := as.IDate(Date) - as.IDate(Sys.Date())]
dt <- dt[dt[time_diff < 0, .("standard_dev" = sd(Rate)), by = Name], on = "Name"]

dt[, modified_rate := ifelse(time_diff > 0, Rate + standard_dev, Rate)]` I would wrap this as a function and post it as an answer, if above computes the right things for you